# Reordering dcast data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Is it possible to reorder the columns of data frame which is a result of dcast() call 
E.x.

Given the data:

```
> dput(copyOfRes)
structure(list(docName = c("doc2", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", 
"doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc2"), day_of_week = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 2)), .Names = c("docName", 
"week_number"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

So, when I use dcast() as follows:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(copyOfRes, docName ~ week_number, length)
```

the result is:

```
  docName 2 11
1    doc1 0 10
2    doc2 1  1
```

I would like to have the data frame with decreasing value of `week_number` as follows:

```
  docName 11  2
1    doc1 10 0
2    doc2 1  1
```

I tried doing `dcast(copyOfRes, docName ~ sort(week_number, decreasing= TRUE), length)`, but it still does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you just reorder your columns after casting?

Comment: @AnandaMahto: Thank you for the answer, but you think reordering `n` (where n would always change) number of columns manually qualifies as a good solution ? I would rather not do it, instead of doing what you suggested.

Comment: no. I would rather make my data representative of what I actually expect it to be: ordered factors.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: I did not understand that. The data is coming from the database. So, the values are going to be dynamic. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: When you read your data in, then, you can make sure the "week_number" is read in or converted as a factor before you start doing any analysis, instead of storing it as numeric. Something like `copyOfRes$week_number <- with(copyOfRes, factor(week_number, levels = sort(unique(week_number), decreasing=TRUE)))` should do it, if you want decreasing ordered factors. Then, when you use other functions, like `summary`, R will tabulate rather than trying to take the `mean` or that column, and `dcast` would be able to do what you want.

Comment: FYI, pre-processing your data that way would also be helpful when doing other things, for example plotting. See [this blog post](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot/) from another SO user where similar advice was made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reorder` here with `rev`

```
dcast(copyOfRes, docName ~ reorder(week_number,rev(week_number)), length)
Using week_number as value column: use value.var to override.
  docName 11 2
1    doc1 10 0
2    doc2  1 1
```

Comment: Nice use of `reorder`. Always forget about that one! +1

Answer (score 14):

You can use `factor()` inside `dcast()` set appropriate order of levels.

```
 dcast(copyOfRes, 
   docName ~ factor(week_number,levels=unique(week_number)), length)
      docName 11 2
    1    doc1 10 0
    2    doc2  1 1
```

Comment: +1. This solves the immediate problem, but I still think the OP should start with factoring the `week_number` variable if it is going to ultimately be treated as a factor.