# Apply a function on a data-frame and return a data-frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
 ID  07  08  09  10  year balance

abc   0   0   0   0  09    2123.00
efg   0   0   0   0  09    780.4
xyz   0   0   0   0  07    2402.9
prq   0   0   0   0  10    123.3
mno   0   0   0   0  07    679
```

I need to fill columns **07, 08, 09 and 10** based on column "**year**" and values in **balance**. 
For each ID, the column corresponding to value in column year is filled with value in balance. Apply this row-by-row.

For example, for 1st row, year is 09, so column 09 for that ID is filled with value 2123.00. Rest all year values remain 0.

For 3rd row, value of 24502.9 is filled in column 07 since its year value is 07. And so on row by row..

**I output should come like this**

```
 ID  07      08  09      10    year  balance

abc   0      0  2123.00  0      09    2123.00
efg   0      0  780.4    0      09    780.4
xyz  2402.9  0   0       0      07    2402.9
prq   0      0   0      123.3   10    123.3
mno  679     0   0       0      07    679
```

**PS: I have already written a for loop for this. I need something faster than for loop. I'm actually dealing with thousands of data.**
I dont know if there is anything similar to apply that returns a data-frame

Comment: maybe dput your dataframe?

Comment: You could use ID, year, balance columns of your data.frame and `dcast` it using `reshape2` & `data.table` with ID as the row and year in the columns and balance in the value 

`library(reshape2)

library(data.table)

final_output<-dcast(setDT(df),ID~year, value.vars="balance")`

Comment: @SatZ Thats does seem to work. Pls write it as an answer

Comment: If I cast be year, will the year get arranged in ascending order? I need it that way

Comment: @DomJo I have added it as an answer, along with the re-ordering

Comment: @SatZ Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Essentially what you want to do is to convert the right side of the data frame from long format to wide format. You can do this using the `spread` function in `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

D <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  07  08  09  10  year balance
abc  0   0   0   0  09    2123.00
efg  0   0   0   0  09    780.4
xyz  0   0   0   0  07    24502.9
prq  0   0   0   0  10    123.3
mno  0   0   0   0  07    679")

D %>%
  select(ID, year, balance) %>%
  spread(year, balance, fill=0) %>%
  bind_cols(D[,c("year","balance")])

#>    ID       7      9    10 year balance
#> 1 abc     0.0 2123.0   0.0    9  2123.0
#> 2 efg     0.0  780.4   0.0    9   780.4
#> 3 mno   679.0    0.0   0.0    7 24502.9
#> 4 prq     0.0    0.0 123.3   10   123.3
#> 5 xyz 24502.9    0.0   0.0    7   679.0
```

Note: the year 08 is missing from the output because it is missing in your example data.

Comment: This will also collapse rows so that you get only one row by `ID` and possibly several years by row, which may very well be desirable (but will then give inexpected results with the `bind_cols`). To keep the amount of rows you can do: `df1[c("ID","year","balance")] %>% mutate(year2=year,balance2=balance) %>% spread(year2,balance2)
`

Comment: I only showed first few records. 08 comes in data following the ones shown. 08, 07 etc means 2008, 2007 etc. The year column can change if a new data comes in. So I can't reference by names

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you want this

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(df1), function(i) {
  df1[i, df1[i, 6]] <- df1[i, 7] 
  df1[i, ]
  }))
```

***Yields***

```
   ID     07 08     09    10 year balance
1 abc    0.0  0 2123.0   0.0   09  2123.0
2 efg    0.0  0  780.4   0.0   09   780.4
3 xyz 2402.9  0    0.0   0.0   07  2402.9
4 prq    0.0  0    0.0 123.3   10   123.3
5 mno  679.0  0    0.0   0.0   07   679.0
```

***Data***

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("abc", 
"efg", "mno", "prq", "xyz"), class = "factor"), `07` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `08` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `09` = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), `10` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c("09", "09", 
"07", "10", "07"), balance = c(2123, 780.4, 2402.9, 123.3, 679
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `data.table` and `reshape2` packages to do this.

You could use ID, year, balance columns of your data.frame and dcast with ID as the row and year in the columns and balance in the value

```
library(reshape2) 
library(data.table) 
final_output<-dcast(setDT(df),ID~year, value.var="balance")
```

If you want to re-order your columns you could use the snippet from the reference below:
[Reordering dcast data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370042/reordering-dcast-data-frame)

```
final_output<-dcast(setDT(df),ID~reorder(year,year), value.var="balance")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 4 lines:

```
df$`07` <- ifelse(test = df$year=='07',yes = df$balance, no=0)
df$`08` <- ifelse(test = df$year=='08',yes = df$balance, no=0) 
df$`09` <- ifelse(test = df$year=='09',yes = df$balance, no=0)
df$`10` <- ifelse(test = df$year=='10',yes = df$balance, no=0)
```

I think it'll work superfast comparing to a loop

Comment: Dude. 07, 08 .. can vary from data to data. This needs to be flexible. SO I don't prefer referencing by name